# iOS 14 present UIMenu from UIView

Tags: ios, ios14, uimenu

iOS 14's `UIMenu` seems to be able to be presented from any `UIBarButtonItem` or `UIButton` / `UIControl`, but I how would I present it from a generic `UIView`?

Answer (score 3):

Add the interaction:

```
let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
menuView.addInteraction(interaction)
```

Add UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate to your controller:

```
extension YourViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
               
      func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { suggestedActions in
            
            // Create an action for sharing
            let share = UIAction(title: "Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { action in
                // Show system share sheet
            }
    
            // Create an action for renaming
            let rename = UIAction(title: "Rename", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")) { action in
                // Perform renaming
            }
    
            // Here we specify the "destructive" attribute to show that it’s destructive in nature
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { action in
                // Perform delete
            }
    
            // Create and return a UIMenu with all of the actions as children
            return UIMenu(title: "", children: [share, rename, delete])
        }
    }
}
```

Now, long-press on the view and see your menu :)

More here: https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide

Comment: I apologize if it wasn't fully clear, I'm looking to present the menu from a generic `UIView` _without_ a long press.

Comment: @JoelFischer You should update your question with those important details. Otherwise this answer perfectly solves what you asked for in your current question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot present a menu directly from a UIView as of now.

The best workaround is to add a UIButton as a subview, and use the UIButton to present the menu. This will work without a long press.

```
button.menu = UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: [], children: menuActions)
button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
view.addSubview(button)
view.sendSubviewToBack(button)
//add necessary constraints to position the button as you please
```

Note: do not use "UIContextMenuInteraction" with the UIButton or it will require a long press. Thanks to @HangarRash for pointing this out.